# how can i open a web page on my phone: webpage is on my computer

Tags: server, apache2

I created a web page on apache server on my ubuntu runnung computer. Now i want to open that web page on my phone (Moto X). How can i do this? I am a new user to ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the same subnet, you would type your computer's local IP Address (which can be found by running the command `ifconfig`) into your phone's web browser.

If you are on another network (wifi or 3G/4G) you would first need to set up port forwarding on your router so web requests can transverse your NAT. Then you would type your Public IP address into your phone's browser. Your public IP can be found by searching `what's my IP` on Google, or by the command `curl icanhazip.com`

NOTE! Some ISPs block common ports such as port 80 (web server). In this case you would have to use an alternate port number like 8080 and specify this value in your browser.

For example, if your public IP is 1.2.3.4 and your port forwarding is set up to the public facing port 8080, you would type `1.2.3.4:8080` into your web browser.

Word of warning though. If something as simple as pulling up a web page running on a local server requires a question on a forum, you should probably do more research before deploying this server unless you want to be attacked. This is a digital age, one small misconfiguration on that server could compromise your entire network.

Be safe,
Lisenby